# Subquery returned more than one value error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following query, but it is throwing an error. It is working fine for some scenarios, depending on the id, but not for all.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

```
Set @NoOfRows = (Select COUNT(*)  from @TempT)

While @i <= @NoOfRows
Begin
  SET @Voucher_No=( select V_No from @TempT where RowID=@i)
  SET @Voucher_Type_No=( select voucher_type_no from @TempT where RowID=@i)
  SET @Voucher_Id=( select Voucher_Id from @TempT where RowID=@i)
  set @strPartyName=''
  set @strPartyName = (Select Party_Name from Cheque_Book where Voucher_No=   @Voucher_No   and Voucher_Type_No=   @Voucher_Type_No   and Company_No=  @Comp_No   and Bank_Account_No= @dbc_Account )

  if NULLIF(@strPartyName,'') IS NULL
  begin
    set @strPartyName =(Select a.account_name from Voucher v inner join account a on v.Account_No = a.account_No where v.Voucher_Id= @Voucher_Id)
    Update @TempT Set Party_Name =@strPartyName Where RowID =@i
    set @i=@i+1
  end
End
Select * from @TempT
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: As error says so Any of your select query return more than one value, thats why you got error? debug that using Print after each select query so that you can find where exactly error is  or create sqlfiddle.

Comment: One of your SELECT stament returning more than one value instead of returning single value. Try running each select statement individually for that particular ID.

Comment: some of your sub queries returning more than on value.. execute sub queries separately and verify

Comment: @temp table returns more than 200 rows, debugging for values for each row is almost impossible

Comment: Seems you are here just to troll instead of helping. @Blam

Answer (score 0):

Its show that your sub-query return more than one value.

You have to modify your sub-query with TOP keyword or give filter (where condition and order by ) more which return only one value.

```
While @i <= @NoOfRows
 Begin

   SET @Voucher_No=( select top 1 V_No from @TempT where RowID=@i)
   SET @Voucher_Type_No=( select top 1 voucher_type_no from @TempT where RowID=@i)
   SET @Voucher_Id=( select top1 Voucher_Id from @TempT where RowID=@i)
......
END
```

To resolve the problem, you just only run the actual select query in while loop which gives the result of more than 2 value like

```
While @i <= @NoOfRows
Begin

   --SET @Voucher_No=( 
   select  V_No from @TempT where RowID=@i --)
   --SET @Voucher_Type_No=( 
   select  voucher_type_no from @TempT where RowID=@i --)
   --SET @Voucher_Id=( 
   select  Voucher_Id from @TempT where RowID=@i --)
    ......
END
```

**UPDATED**
This is sample data to understand what happened with you and how to resolve it.

```
declare @department table (deptid int, name varchar(50))
declare @emp table (id int, name varchar(50), deptid int)

insert into @department values (1,'d1'), (2,'d2'),(3,'d3'),(4,'d4')
insert into @emp values(1,'ajay',1), (2,'ajay1',1),(3,'ajay3' ,2),(4,'ajay4' ,3),(5,'ajay5' ,4)


select * from @department where deptid = 1

/* suppose your sub-query like */
--1. this give result
select * from @department where deptid = (select deptid from @emp where id = 1)

--2. this give result, but may be get wrong result as it take top 1.
select * from @department where deptid = (select top 1 deptid from @emp )

--3. this give error same you have
select * from @department where deptid = (select deptid from @emp)

--to resolve the above error, just uncomment below sub-query.
--select deptid from @emp
```

Comment: dear whatever your value, you just directly run on anther window.  Or just run my second option as only select query add in while loop. try to give or execute small set of result which you know before run the query like @noofRows = 1 or give 2

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting variable using sub-query, set variable as shown below.

```
SELECT @NoOfRows = COUNT(*) FROM @TempT

WHILE @i <= @NoOfRows
BEGIN
    SELECT @Voucher_No = V_No FROM @TempT WHERE RowID=@i
    SELECT @Voucher_Type_No = voucher_type_no FROM @TempT WHERE RowID=@i
    SELECT @Voucher_Id = Voucher_Id FROM @TempT where RowID=@i
    SET @strPartyName=''

    SELECT @strPartyName =  Party_Name FROM Cheque_Book WHERE Voucher_No = @Voucher_No AND Voucher_Type_No = @Voucher_Type_No   AND Company_No=  @Comp_No   AND Bank_Account_No= @dbc_Account
    IF NULLIF(@strPartyName,'') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @strPartyName = a.account_name FROM Voucher v INNER JOIN account a ON v.Account_No = a.account_No WHERE v.Voucher_Id= @Voucher_Id
        UPDATE @TempT SET Party_Name = @strPartyName WHERE RowID = @i
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
END 
SELECT * FROM @TempT
```

Answer (score 0):

I see answers here for the issue where the following queries fail because their subqueries return multiple values:

```
SET @Voucher_No = (SELECT [V_No] FROM @TempT WHERE [RowID] = @i);
SET @Voucher_Type_No = (SELECT [voucher_type_no] FROM @TempT WHERE [RowID] = @i);
SET @Voucher_Id = (SELECT [Voucher_Id] FROM @TempT WHERE [RowID] = @i);
```

There are mainly two proposed solutions in those answers:

1. `SET @Variable = (SELECT TOP (1) [Field] FROM [Table] WHERE ...);`, or
2. `SELECT @Variable = [Field] FROM [Table] WHERE ...);`.

To my surprise, the second approach is considered to be the preferred approach. There are a few important things to consider, however.

First: if the SELECT-query returns multiple results, the value of `@Variable` will become the **last** retrieved value from the query's result set. This has to be regarded when an ORDER BY clause is specified.

So the query below will return `5` instead of `1`:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ([ID] INT);
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (1), (3), (2), (5), (4);

DECLARE @Variable INT = 42;
SELECT @Variable = [ID] FROM @TempTable ORDER BY [ID];

SELECT @Variable AS [@Variable];
```

Second: if `@Variable` already contains a value and the SELECT query does not produce any results (0 rows), the value of `@Variable` remains unchanged!

So the query below will produce result `42` instead of `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ([ID] INT);
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (1), (3), (2), (5), (4);

DECLARE @Variable INT = 42;
SELECT @Variable = [ID] FROM @TempTable WHERE [ID] = 6;

SELECT @Variable AS [@Variable];
```

For all these reasons, my personal preference lies with the `SET @Variable = (SELECT TOP (1) ...)` approach.